# Separate data into class boxes

Tags: javascript

Right, so i have a series of class div's and I can't think how to output one entry in each one.

```
<a class='foo'></a>
<a class='foo'></a>
<a class='foo'></a>

bar = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

arr ['cheese','soap','glove'];

for(i=0;i<bar.length;i++) {
bar[x].appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
}
```

this inputs cheesesoapglove into each class div box... how do i separate out each string in the array to go into a single div box like the below:

```
<a class='foo'>cheese</a>
<a class='foo'>soap</a>
<a class='foo'>glove</a>
```

Comment: if you're the one who upvoted my answer, thanks! At the same time, if you believe it answered your question, you might want to accept it as the correct one (big checkmark underneath the voting buttons), thanks again!

Comment: Also or people looking at this page you will come to the problem that the output will always be the final product of the if statement. http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is replace `x` in `bar` with `i`, do some cleanup of the code, and you're good to go:

```
var bar = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

var arr = ['cheese','soap','glove'];

for(i=0;i<bar.length;i++) {
    bar[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
}
```

You could also shorten your `for` loop like this:

```
for(i=0;i<bar.length;i++) {
    bar[i].innerHTML = arr[i];
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nr3HQ/)**